# Is it possible to put a binary file (say a .mp3 file) as a single message in Kafka? If yes, how?

Tags: java, message-queue, apache-kafka, datastore, kafka-producer-api

I am relatively new to Apache Kafka. As a part of a tiny project, I was trying to put a text log file in Kafka as a single message. I encountered some encoding errors. Kafka's java API (as I understood), contains provisions for mostly String encoding.

As a work-around, I threw my log file line by line in Kafka where each line represents a single message, but this doesn't solve my initial problem statement- one file as one message.

Answer (score 1):

You should've included the error message(s).

Regardless, it should be possible to send an arbitrary large file to Kafka in a single message, as long as [maximum message size setting](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#configuration) on producer/broker/consumer allows that.
Brokers don't care about the type of data, since they store data in binary format.
BTW I'm not sure how efficient it would be to use Kafka for large files, since according to LinkedIn's tests, the optimal buffer size is in the region 64 - 128 kB.
I would do some tests if I were you :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Marco, but the 'how' part of my question still remains unanswered. How would I put in a 93KB amr recording in kafka if I want to?

Comment: When you send larger files as payload, it's important to have zero-copy. See here: http://search-hadoop.com/m/uyzND1yOLCIogQoO1&subj=Re+Kafka+to+transport+binary+files  E.g. you can use [kafkacat](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat). For example: `$ kafkacat -P -b mybroker -t filedrop -p 0 myfile1.amr`